Getting "Tag Lost" Exception When Writing to NFC-V Tag in Android (Using Addressed Commands)
I'm working on an Android app where I need to write data to an NFC-V tag. I'm using the transceive() method to write single blocks to the NFC tag, but I keep encountering a "Tag Lost" exception during the write process. I've implemented retries and ensured the connection is established before every write attempt, but the issue persists.
Here's a summary of my setup:
Setup:
Android app uses NFC-V to communicate with a tag.
Writing a specific output current to a designated block on the tag (Block 5 in this case).
Using addressed commands to ensure communication is reliable across different Android devices.
Implemented retries to reconnect if the connection fails or the tag is lost.
The Issue:
I keep encountering a "Tag Lost" exception even though I've implemented reconnection and retry mechanisms. The issue occurs when I try to write to a block, and the tag moves or loses connection during the process.
Relevant Code:
This is the function I use to write the output current to the NFC-V tag:
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
fun writeToNfcTag(tag: Tag) {
    val nfcV = NfcV.get(tag)
    val tagUid = tag.id  // Retrieve the UID of the NFC tag

    if (nfcV != null) {
        var retries = 0
        val maxRetries = 5
        var success = false

        while (retries < maxRetries && !success) {
            try {
                // Reconnect to the tag if the connection is lost
                reconnectNfcTag(nfcV)

                val outputCurrent = setCurrentValue.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0

                // Convert the output current to bytes (big-endian)
                val outputCurrentBytes = byteArrayOf(
                    (outputCurrent shr 8 and 0xFF).toByte(),
                    (outputCurrent and 0xFF).toByte()
                )

                // Write to Block 5 (output current) using addressed command
                val blockAddress = 0x20  // Block 5 stores output current
                val writeSuccess = writeSingleBlock(nfcV, blockAddress, outputCurrentBytes, tagUid)

                if (writeSuccess) {
                    Log.d("ProgramFragment", "Output Current successfully written: $outputCurrent mA")
                    nfcInstructions.text = "Write successful. Output current updated to $outputCurrent mA."
                    success = true  // Mark success
                } else {
                    throw IOException("Write failed")
                }

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("ProgramFragment", "Error writing to NFC-V tag, retrying...", e)
                retries++
                nfcInstructions.text = "Write failed. Retrying... ($retries/$maxRetries)"
            } finally {
                try {
                    nfcV.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e("ProgramFragment", "Error closing NFC-V connection", e)
                }
            }
        }

        if (!success) {
            nfcInstructions.text = "Write failed after $maxRetries attempts. Please try again."
        }

        (activity as MainActivity).isWritingNfc = false

    } else {
        Log.e("ProgramFragment", "NFC-V not supported on this tag")
        nfcInstructions.text = "NFC-V is not supported on this tag. Please use a compatible tag."
        (activity as MainActivity).isWritingNfc = false
    }
}

// Helper function to write a single block using addressed command
fun writeSingleBlock(nfcV: NfcV, blockAddress: Int, dataBlock: ByteArray, tagUid: ByteArray): Boolean {
    val cmd = byteArrayOf(
        0x60.toByte(),  // FLAGS
        0x21.toByte(),  // WRITE_SINGLE_BLOCK
        *tagUid,  // UID of the tag
        (blockAddress and 0xFF).toByte()  // Block address
    )
    val fullCmd = cmd + dataBlock  // Append the data block to the command
    return try {
        nfcV.transceive(fullCmd)
        true  // Successfully written
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("ProgramFragment", "Write failed for block $blockAddress", e)
        false
    }
}

// Helper function to reconnect to the tag
fun reconnectNfcTag(nfcV: NfcV, retries: Int = 5): Boolean {
    var attempts = 0
    while (attempts < retries) {
        try {
            if (!nfcV.isConnected) {
                nfcV.connect()
            }
            return true  // Successfully reconnected
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            attempts++
            Log.e("NFC", "Error reconnecting to NFC tag, attempt $attempts", e)
        }
    }
    return false  // Failed to reconnect after retries
}

What I've Tried:

Implementing retries for both connection and writing attempts (up to 5 retries).

Reconnecting to the NFC tag before each write operation.

Using addressed commands with the tag UID to ensure reliability across devices.


Question:
How can I prevent the "Tag Lost" exception when writing data to an NFC-V tag, and is there any further optimization I can implement to improve the reliability of the write operation?

What API are you using to get the tag object, enableForegroundDispatch or enableReaderMode? as using enableForegroundDispatch can be very unreliable in practise. You don't seem to be checking the response of the nfcV.transceive command, so you won't know if the command is successful. Quite often an error return from the Tag also puts it in to a halt state and this is not recoverable from until re-detect. What's the make and model of the NFC-V Tag as it's datasheet and transceive return might give you a clue to the problem.

Most of the "recover" stuff you have put in place is probably worthless and never going to work as the Tag needs to be re-initialised by removing it from the RF field and on later version of Android trying to re-use the Tag object will cause a Security Exception.

I'm trying to read and write data off of a ISO-15693 tag

There are many makes and models of  ISO-15693 tags, so that does not help and you have not answered the other questions

I am using enableReaderMode. I do not know the make and model of the nfc tag as the driver is from a supplier that we are trying to program.

That just leave what is the byte array returned from the nfcV.transceive that might help understand what is going wrong.
